# Is a coarse moduli space whose objects have no automorphisms also fine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

We work over the complex numbers $ k = \mathbb{C} $.

Let $ F $ be a moduli problem, i.e. a contravariant functor $ F : \text{Sch}/k \rightarrow \text{Sets} $. Suppose that $ M $ is a coarse moduli scheme for the moduli problem $ F $. Also suppose that the objects represented by this moduli problem, i.e. the objects corresponding to $ F(k) \cong M(k) $ have no non-trivial automorphisms.

Is $ M $ also a fine moduli scheme for the moduli problem $ F $?

I am aware of algebraic stacks but I would prefer an answer entirely about schemes, if possible.

I suspect this is false but haven't really been able to come up with a concrete counterexample, even for topological objects like triangles. Thank you for any help.

Edit. For clarity, I will add the definitions I'm using.

A coarse moduli scheme for $ F $ is a scheme $ M $ over $ \mathbb{C} $ and a natural transformation $ t : F \rightarrow \text{Hom} ( - , M) $ such that (1) for every algebraically closed field $ \Omega $ (containing $ \mathbb{C} $) we have $ t : F(\Omega) \rightarrow M(\Omega) $ is a bijection. (2) Given any scheme $ N $ and a natural transformation $ u : F \rightarrow \text{Hom} ( - , N) $, there exists a unique morphism of schemes $ s : M \rightarrow N $ such that $ u = st $.

A fine moduli scheme for $ F $ is a scheme $ M $ and a natural isomorphism $ t : F \rightarrow \text{Hom} ( - , M) $.

Using these definitions, it is clear that if a coarse and fine moduli scheme exist, they are unique upto a unique isomorphism.

Comment: It depends on what you mean. Are you assuming that $F$ is itself an algebraic stack? What does a moduli space mean? What does a coarse moduli scheme mean?

Comment: @Alex Youcis sorry I should have been more clear. F is as is defined in the question, no algebraic stack here. I will add the definitions of coarse and fine moduli scheme I'm using.